# Data Mapper lookup mapping

Tags: mule, esb

I wanted to do a lookup data mapping using data mapper between source and target. I have a field priority on both source and target. But he values used for source and Target are different. For priority Source sends critical but Target has no Critical value they call it something else. Is this possible. If so could you please guide on how to approach this

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+DataMapper+Lookup+Tables